# How can I show that $D_{2n} \cong C_n \rtimes C_2 $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, dihedral-groups, semidirect-product

Let $D_8 := \langle a,b \mid a^4 = 1 = b^2, bab = a^{-1}\rangle$

I'm trying to formally show that

$$D_{8} \cong C_4 \rtimes C_2 = \langle s\rangle \rtimes \langle t \rangle$$

My book gives as hint to consider the map $\phi: C_2 = \langle t \rangle \to Aut(C_4) = \{id, .^{-1}\}\cong C_2 $ that sends $1 \mapsto id, t \mapsto .^{-1}$ and then show that

$$D_8 \cong C_4 \rtimes_\phi C_2$$

The right-action associated with this map is given by:

$$*: C_4 \times C_2 \to C_4:$$

where $s*t =(s)((t)\phi))$ (I follow the convention in Isaac's algebra book where I write $(x)f$ instead of $f(x)$).

I tried to define an isomorphism explicitly:

$$D_8 \to C_4 \rtimes_\phi C_2$$

by mapping

$$a^jb^k \mapsto (k,j) \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \cong C_2 \times C_4$$

where $j \in \{0, \dots, 3\}, k = 0,1$.

This seems to be the only sensible choice for such a map.

How can I show that this map is a bijection (I see that injection or surjection is sufficient, and I also know that this is well-defined), and thus an isomorphism? Is there an easier way to see the isomorphism?

Comment: Which book are you using?

Comment: Martin Isaacs "Algebra, A graduate course".

Comment: Since $b^2=e$, $b^{-1}=b$, so the LHS of relation $bab=a^{-1}$ can be written as conjunction of $a$ by $b$, so one has an inner automorphism . . .

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Can you be somewhat more explicit? How does that exactly help?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can. My understanding of semidirect products is based on their presentations. However, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/160870/104041) is a question that'll be of some help, I reckon :)

Comment: *conjugation.  Sorry: autocorrect . . .

Comment: Thank you! I will look into it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Semidirect product structure of Dihedral group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426989/semidirect-product-structure-of-dihedral-group).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde How exactly is this a duplicate?

Comment: For $k=1$ it shows that $D_n\cong \Bbb Z/m\rtimes \Bbb Z/2$, so the result you want..